# Waiting on Meteor.user() for plublication

Tags: meteor

I'm new to Meteor and I want to return only the character which is owned by the currently logged in user in my publication

```
Meteor.publish 'characters', ->
    Characters.findOne(userId: Meteor.userId())
```

But how can I make sure that the userId is retrieved before I call the publication? Right now it returns and empty array in the client, unless i specifically hardcode the current user's ID into the query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this.userId` in publish methods, and return a cursor (i.e `find` instead of `findOne`, even if there is one result):

```
Meteor.publish 'characters', ->
    Characters.find(userId: this.userId)
```

Comment: actually, if I wanted to have that character available in the client at all times, like Meteor.user(), how would I go about implementing that?

Comment: You would have to search for it using `user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId)`. Only publish functions are like this because they are re-run when you log in or out & only the returned cursors are reactive (contrary to how helpers work, which are based on Deps)